# Python: what exactly does .payload in scapy?

Tags: python, frame, scapy

I'm trying to understand a Python script that analyzes beacon frames. But I'm stuck at something called .payload. Looking at the Python documentation and doing research didn't help me out. I found out that the payload is the data carried by the frame.

```
def insert_ap(pkt):
    ## Done in the lfilter param
    # if Dot11Beacon not in pkt and Dot11ProbeResp not in pkt:
    #     return
    bssid = pkt[Dot11].addr3
    if bssid in aps:
        return
    p = pkt[Dot11Elt]
    cap = pkt.sprintf("{Dot11Beacon:%Dot11Beacon.cap%}"
                      "{Dot11ProbeResp:%Dot11ProbeResp.cap%}").split('+')
    ssid, channel = None, None
    crypto = set()
    while isinstance(p, Dot11Elt):
        if p.ID == 0:
            ssid = p.info
        elif p.ID == 3:
            channel = ord(p.info)
        elif p.ID == 48:
            crypto.add("WPA2")
        elif p.ID == 221 and p.info.startswith('\x00P\xf2\x01\x01\x00'):
            crypto.add("WPA")
        p = p.payload # HERE IT IS
    if not crypto:
        if 'privacy' in cap:
            crypto.add("WEP")
        else:
            crypto.add("OPN")
    print "NEW AP: %r [%s], channed %d, %s" % (ssid, bssid, channel,
                                               ' / '.join(crypto))
    aps[bssid] = (ssid, channel, crypto)

aps = {}
sniff(iface='mon0', prn=insert_ap, store=False,
      lfilter=lambda p: (Dot11Beacon in p or Dot11ProbeResp in p))
```

The payload function is written in a while loop. The loop is active as long as the packet is an instance of Dot11Elt. But what does .payload do that it's no longer Dot11Elt (?)

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know anything about the protocol you're working with, but that line is pretty obviously replacing the value of `p` with the value of `p.payload`.  That is, it's not "doing" anything to the contents of `p`; it's assigning a new value to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

packet.payload is just a pointer to the next layer.

Take a look at the [Scapy documentation](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/build_dissect.html#layers).

For example, if pkt were constructed as such:

```
pkt = Dot11()/foo()/IP()/TCP()
```

In your example, `p` is initially set to `pkt[Dot11]`.  Therefore, `p.payload` is `pkt[Dot11].payload`, which points to the `foo` object.  At the end of the loop, `p` is advanced to `p.payload`.  As long as `p` is of type *Dot11Elt*, the loop will keep running.

If we assume that both `Dot11`, and `foo` are of type *Dot11Elt*, then the loop will run until `p` is pointing to the IP layer.